# Как программировать Python с командой онлайн?

Tags: python, ide

Я с другом решил создать общий проект но столкнулись с проблемой, нам нужно редактировать 1 код в реальном времени. Мы попробовали сервис replit но нам он не подошёл т.к. он не поддерживает некоторые библиотеки. Есть ли что-то подобное подскажите?

Comment: Например, github. Запускаете каждый у себя в браузере codespaces и работаете.

Comment: @Kromster язык python

Comment: У Jetbrains есть Code With Me, но нужно смотреть какие возможности доступны для Comunity Edition. Но всегда можно включить активировать 30 дней триала.

Comment: "В реальном времени" - это типа как в гугл документах? Что за задача такая? Это разве что для обучения могло бы понадобиться, но не для программирования.

Comment: @insolor Да, как в гугл документах, это нужно чтобы вместе работать над одним кодом а не разбивать этот проект на кучу файлов.

Comment: Это очень плохая идея. И редактирование в реальном времени, и один файл для проекта. Вы друг другу так будете больше мешать, тем более в одном мегафайле.

Comment: Онлайн формат одновременного редактирования хорош только для собеседований. Для всего остального есть Git.

Answer (score 0):

Есть VSCode и в нём есть расширение live share (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare) активируешь на одном устройстве и тебе выдаётся ссылка(слева снизу кнопка live share нажимаешь и ссылка автоматом копируется в буфер обмена). Друг переходит по ней и в всплывающем окне нажимает открыть через VSCode или ctrl + alt + j в программе и вставляет ссылку